# Can I test for significant difference between samples of a single time series?

Tags: time-series, anova, post-hoc

I am trying to find a statistically sound way of analyzing my time series data. The data and questions are pretty simple:

**Experiment setup**

I have an estimate of the rate at which a crustacean consumed (i.e., grazed) a particular seaweed species. I started the experiment with 6 treatment units (seaweed + crustacean) and 6 control units (seaweed only). Starting at t = 0 hrs, I weighed each seaweed every 24 hrs, with the last measurement taken at 168 hrs. The first thing I did with the data was to calculate the change in weight from one day to the next for each unit. Then, I averaged the change in weight of the controls for each sample time to get a 'control weight change per day' (most likely water loss). I then subtracted that control mean from the treatment data to get an estimate of grazing rate (g of seaweed consumed per day).

**The goal**

Below is the grazing rate per day. The exponential regression (R^2 = 0.97) shows that the grazing increased exponentially over time, showing definitive evidence of grazing activity increase. However, I would like to identify at which time points the grazing changes significantly, as I want to interpret the grazing activity within the context of the stages of degradation of the seaweed.

To do so, I tried using an ANOVA, testing whether the mean grazing rate differed between sampling time. I though this might work, considering I am not comparing different seaweed species, only time periods. The difference was significant (obviously, and not the result I focused on). So then I did a Tukeys post hoc test, to find which groups were different from each other - and the differences are represented with the letters in the graph. If I were to interpret the current graph, I would say it shows three "sections" of consumption - There is a significant increase in consumption between 72 and 96 hrs, and another around the 144-hour mark. I can then tie this information to the observed stages of decomposition.

[image: Estimated grazing rate of seaweed by crustaceans, over time. n = 6. Exponential regression and ANOVA Tukey's post-hoc test results shown.]

**The question**

Obviously, I know the time periods are not independent from each other... so the ANOVA assumptions are not met. Is there some test for time-series that could give me a result similar to the Tukey's post-hoc, which shows the significant difference between time periods for a single treatment/time series?

Thank you in advance.